# How to convert the timestamp in Stackoverflow data dump into Oracle Timestamp format?

Tags: database, oracle, timestamp

How do I convert this timestamp ('2008-08-03T18:06:30.913') in Stackoverflow data dump into Oracle Timestamp format? What should be included in place of the question marks in the function below?

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2008-08-03T18:06:30.913','YYYY-MM-DD??HH24:MI:SS.FFF')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL> select to_timestamp('2008-08-03T18:06:30.913','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
  2    from dual
  3  /

TO_TIMESTAMP('2008-08-03T18:06:30.913','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-AUG-08 06.06.30.913000000 PM

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should work

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2008-08-03T18:06:30.913','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"Z"')
```

This is in accordance to [ISO 8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and T indicates the start of the time part.

(Can't run now to check this) Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can replace the T with a space. I don't think the "T" in the string has any specific meaning. Looks like its used as a separator between date & time. You can use the replace function of oracle to remove the "T"